# How to disable verification for specific controller in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

There is controller with methods. Request validation must be disable for one of method. I try use attribute `[ValidateInput(false)]`, but visual studio cannot find it. I use .net core 2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no request validation in ASP.NET Core.